# How filter a list by date from request.data?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have this code:

```
final date1 = DateTime(2022, 4, 11); 
final date2 = DateTime.now();
late var difference;

int daysBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
    to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
    return (to.difference(from).inHours / 24).round();
  }
```

I can do it in a Listview.builder because I have my index and I use it to see how many days are between 2 dates.

I'm using Flutter Riverpod and I would like to make a filter by days left.

Somthing like this:

```
enum DataFilter{ all, next, almostDone, done }

final dataFilterProvider = StateProvider<DataFilter>((ref) {
  return DataFilter.all;
});


final filteredDataProvider = Provider<List<Data>>((ref) {
  final selectedFilter = ref.watch(dataFilterProvider);
  final datas = ref.watch(datasFilterProvider);

  switch (selectedFilter) {
    case DataFilter.all:
      return data;

    case DataFilter.next:
      return data;

    case DataFilter.almostDone:
    return data;
    
    case DataFilter.done:
      return data;
  }
});
```

But my mind doesn't give me any ideas.

This provider is an example.

How can I make a filter my data by difference between days.

1 filter daysBetween all

1 filter daysBetween >= 15 (next)

1 filter daysBetween > 0 and < 15 (almostDone)

1 filter daysBetween <= 0 (done)

This is my page where a I have my code working good, but I would like to manage with provider (Riverpod)

```
class HomeScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends ConsumerState {
...

 int daysBetween(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
    to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
    return (to.difference(from).inHours / 24).round();
  }

  formatDate(DateTime date) {
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy').format(date);
    return formattedDate;
  }

  final today = DateTime.now();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(
  
  body: SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.74,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: datasState.datas.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final data = datasState.datas[index];
                final difference = daysBetween(
                  today,
                  datasState.datas[index].done,  //done is a date
                );
                return Padding(

...
```

And here is where I show my data with difference colors depending of "difference" variable

Comment: Where is the data? Both `selectedFilter` and `data` watch `dataFilterProvider`.

Comment: You right Dhafin Rayhan. I fixed. But that is an example.

Comment: In `daysBetween` why do you recreate new `DateTime` objects which are the same as the objects passed to the method?

Comment: @Roslan Amir, I'm learning flutter. If you know how can I do better, show me how please. I appreciate every help. Thanks

Comment: You can replace the whole function with this builtin function: `final daysBetween = to.difference(from).inDays;` I don't use RiverPod so I cannot help you with the original problem.